# Extend axis on c3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I want to show a user his financials for the past week, oftentimes the user will not have financials for each of the seven days. However, with c3.js, it will extend the 'endpoint-value', to the end of the axis, is there a way to prevent this? Or do I have to manually add a zero-value to the end of each series so it won't be extended by c3.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a max value for the x axis, like so

```
...
axis: {
  x: {
    max: 7
  }
}
...
```

http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-max

Comment: No, I want the axis to go beyond the last value, basically to show that "for this past week, Monday through Saturday had sales, but Sunday is empty". I don't want to stop one day early at Saturday. How would this be done?